# Python - Increment in Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I can't figure why `negative` won't increment, it keeps resetting back to 0.

```
for line in neg_file:
    line = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-]', '', line)
    if line == word:
        negative += 1
        print "N: " + str(negative)
```

*Sorry about the delay.*

**UPDATE**

Full code:

```
tweets = json.loads(open('tweets.json').read())
pos_file = open("words/positive.txt", "r+")
neg_file = open("words/negative.txt", "r+")

list = []
dict = {}

positive = 1 #this part works fine
positive += 2
print positive
dict['positive'] = positive
print dict

negative = 0
positive = 0

for x in range(len(tweets)):
    text = tweets[x]['text']
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if len(word)>3)
    text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', text)
    words = text.split(" ")
    dict['word_count'] = len(words)
    #exact match
    #print words
    for word in words:
        pos_file = open("words/positive.txt", "r+")
        for line in pos_file:
            line = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-]', '', line)
            if line == word:
                positive += 1 #str(word) - wasnt working for string concat, so i switched to numbers
                print positive
        pos_file.close()
        dict['positive']  = positive 
        positive = 0
        negative = 0
        neg_file = open("words/negative.txt", "r+")

        for line in neg_file:
            line = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-]', '', line)
            if line == word:
                negative += 1
                print "N: " + str(negative)

        neg_file.close()
        dict['negative']  = negative
        negative = 0

    print dict
    list.append(dict)
    dict.clear()
print list
```

OUTPUT

`3`
`{'positive': 3}`
`{'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'word_count': 9}`
`1`
`{'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'word_count': 13}`
`1`
`inevitable`
`N: 1`
`loss`
`N: 1`
`{'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'word_count': 15}`
`1`
`{'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'word_count': 11}`
`stumbles`
`N: 1`
`{'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'word_count': 12}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the `negative` variable before stepping into the loop:

```
negative = 0
for line in neg_file:
    # no changes
```

The way you are proceeding, it is "created" every single loop.

Comment: @AdegokeA really ? You should include that in your code up top.

Comment: How would it reset if it weren't defined before the loop? As far as I can tell, if he's not defining it before the loop it should throw a name error..?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson his code would throw a name error if the `negative += 1` instruction didn't exist. & as you probably know, assigning a value to a variable **creates** the variable if it does not already exist.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're saying, `negative += 1` throws a name error if `negative` isn't already defined.

Comment: You are right, `negative += 1` does require `negative` to be previously defined, which makes perfect sense. So the OP must've already defined it in his code, or he forgot to mention the `NameError`.

Comment: so, in summary, neither the question nor this answer makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was re-setting `positive` and `negative` back to zero pre-maturely. They should be reset after the `for word in words:` loop.